# Percorrer um array e inserir valores no meio dele

Tags: javascript

Preciso de criar um programa em JS que recebe uma requencia de algarismos do utilizador (ex: 11223655871) e devolve a sequencia com '-' entre numeros pares e '#' entre numeros impares, ou seja, o resultado será: 1#12-2365#587#1

Comment: O resultado não seria `1#1#2-2-3#6-5#5#8-7#1#` ou existe outra condição não explicada na pergunta?

Comment: Não, o '-' apenas é inserido entre números pares e o '#' entre números que sejam ímpares. Entre um numero par e um numero ímpar não é inserido nenhum valor.

Comment: entendi, entre DOIS números pares e entre DOIS números ímpares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var num=11223655871;
var result="";

var digits = num.toString().split('');

var realDigits = digits.map(Number);

for(i = 0; i < realDigits.length; i++)
{
    var value1 = realDigits[i];
    var value2 = realDigits[i+1];
    
    result += value1;
    
    if(value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0) {
        result += "#";
    }else if(value1 % 2 == 0 && value2 % 2 == 0){
        result += "-";
    }
}

result = result.substring(0,(result.length - 1));

console.log(result);
```

**Conceitos:**

- O método toString() retorna uma string representando o objeto
- O método split() divide um objeto String em um array de strings ao separar a string em substrings
- O método do mapa() cria uma nova matriz com os resultados da chamada de uma função para cada elemento da matriz.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar a função Array.prototype.reduce, observar o último caracter do primeiro argumento e o segundo argumento, ver se são os dois pares/ímpares, e retornar o número com potencialmente o símbolo no meio.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que expressão regular seja a melhor forma de formatar sua string.

```js
let meuNum = 11223655871;
let numFormatdo = `${meuNum}`.replace(/([13579])([13579])/g, '$1#$2')
                             .replace(/([02468])([02468])/g, '$1-$2');
                            
console.log(numFormatdo);
```